# Setting table height appears to adds margin-top instead

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I'm trying to make a scrollable table, with the table height set. However, when I try to set the height, it adds a margin on top of the table instead of adjusting the height of the actual table. 
I want only the table to scroll (Not the date above it) and eventually hope to make the column titles sticky.

You can see what I'm talking about here: http://jsfiddle.net/m5s87hb0/

This is my html:

```
<div class='box-style-1' id='timesheet-box'>
<span class='box-title'>Time Sheet<span>
<div id='table-wrapper'>
    <table id='timesheet'>
        <thead>
            <th id='timesheet-date' colspan="5">00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000</th>
        </thead>
        <div id='table-scroll'>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='col-titles'>
                    <th>Jobs</th>
                    <th>Task</th>
                    <th>In</th>
                    <th>Out</th>
                    <th>Hours</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job 1</td>
                    <td>Task 1</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job 2</td>
                    <td>Task 2</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job 3</td>
                    <td>Task 3</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job 4</td>
                    <td>Task 4</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job 5</td>
                    <td>Task 5</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>00:00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>    
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.box-style-1 {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #D1D3D4;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box-title {
    display: block;
    background: #D15F32;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: ;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#timesheet-box {
    width: 78%;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
#table-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
}
#timesheet {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #3a3a3c;
    height: 100%;
}
#timesheet-date {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#table-scroll {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
tbody {

}
th, td {
   border: 1px solid #3a3a3c;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 22px;
   height: 40px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the div around tbody, move it around the table and your table will scroll

```
<div id='table-scroll'>
  <table id='timesheet'>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

**edit**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLmqbK

To fix the header, you must add a position absolute to the header and fix its height. The rest of your table will go up so add a padding-top to the around div for this height value to fix it. Also add a background to hide scrolled content below.

```
thead {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  height:40px;
  background:white;
}
#table-scroll {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top:23px; /* I don't know where the 17 other px come from in your code but who cares :) */
}
```

Comment: They want to be able to keep the table's title/header stuck to the top while the body of the table scrolls.

Comment: But I don't want the date on top to scroll, just the body of the table. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I did it recently, but I needed to use position absolute on the header and control its top value with javascript  (I may try to find the code if you want). I'm not sure it's possible only with html/css

Comment: @Luckyn I want to keep it to pure html/css if possible.

Comment: I guess I can try moving the date out of the table

Comment: @Webhead check the edit, the only issue is that the header tr don't take 100% width for an unknown reason...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the date out of the table.